# Creating an anonymous object and call a function from it dynamically

Tags: php, uri

I'm trying to create some kind of dispatcher for my web (cuz i have to do it manually and idk how can i do this)

```
$uri = array_filter(explode("/", filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, "PATH_INFO")));
$_SERVER["URI"] = $uri;

switch (sizeof($uri)) {
    case 0:
        error();
        exit(0);
        break;
    case 1:
        call_user_func("$uri[1]::__construct");
        break;
    default :
        call_user_method_array("$uri[2]", call_user_func("$uri[1]::getInstance"));
        break;
}
```

That's what i have but i get this:

- Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\wamp\www\BACK\index.php on line 180
- Deprecated: Function call_user_method_array() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\BACK\index.php on line 180
- Warning: call_user_method_array() expects exactly 3 parameters, 2 given in C:\wamp\www\BACK\index.php on line 180

Sending http://localhost/BACK/index.php/Page/data?asd=1

and

- Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method Page::__construct() cannot be called statically in C:\wamp\www\BACK\index.php on line 17

Sending http://localhost/BACK/index.php/Page?asd=1

I know i'm totally wrong but i can't find help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my function and is working correctly now

```
$uri = array_filter(explode("/", filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, "PATH_INFO")));
$_SERVER["URI"] = $uri;

switch (sizeof($uri)) {
    case 0:
        error();
        exit(0);
        break;
    case 1:
        $refClass = new ReflectionClass("$uri[1]");
        $class_instance = $refClass->newInstanceArgs((array) null);
        break;
    default :
        $refClass = new ReflectionClass("$uri[1]");
        $class_instance = $refClass->newInstanceArgs((array) null);
        $class_instance->$uri[2]();
        break;
}
```